# OpenERP Invalid XML for View Architecture in account banking export payment module

Tags: xml, odoo

I am trying to install module called: account banking payment export. It gives me Invalid XML for View Architecture error.
I checked the server logs:

```
2013-11-03 07:58:38,499 14957 INFO itmeedia openerp.modules.module: module account_banking_payment_export: creating or updating database tables
2013-11-03 07:58:38,529 14957 INFO itmeedia openerp.modules.loading: module account_banking_payment_export: loading view/account_payment.xml
2013-11-03 07:58:38,544 14957 ERROR itmeedia openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_ui_view: Can't render view  for model: payment.order
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 126, in _check_render_view
    fvg = self.pool.get(view.model).fields_view_get(cr, uid, view_id=view.id, view_type=view.type, context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 2239, in fields_view_get
    arch=apply_view_inheritance(cr, user, source, sql_res['id']),
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 2197, in apply_view_inheritance
    source = apply_inheritance_specs(source, view_arch, view_id)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 2181, in apply_inheritance_specs
    raise_view_error("Element '%s' not found in parent view '%%(parent_xml_id)s'" % tag, inherit_id)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 2074, in raise_view_error
    %  (child_view.xml_id, self._name, error_msg))
AttributeError: View definition error for inherited view 'account_pain.view_payment_order_form_inherit' on model 'payment.order': Element '<button name="set_done">' not found in parent view 'account_payment.view_payment_order_form'
2013-11-03 07:58:38,548 14957 ERROR itmeedia openerp.tools.convert: Parse error in /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/account_banking_payment_export/view/account_payment.xml:7: 
<record id="view_banking_payment_order_form_1" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">account.payment.order.form.banking-1</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="account_payment.view_payment_order_form"/>
            <field name="model">payment.order</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <data>
                    <xpath expr="//button[@string='Make Payments']" position="attributes">
                        <attribute name="name">launch_wizard</attribute>
                    </xpath>
                </data>
            </field>
        </record>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 847, in parse
    self._tags[rec.tag](self.cr, rec, n)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 814, in _tag_record
    id = self.pool.get('ir.model.data')._update(cr, self.uid, rec_model, self.module, res, rec_id or False, not self.isnoupdate(data_node), noupdate=self.isnoupdate(data_node), mode=self.mode, context=rec_context )
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 967, in _update
    res_id = model_obj.create(cr, uid, values, context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 103, in create
    return super(view, self).create(cr, uid, values, context)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 4478, in create
    self._validate(cr, user, [id_new], context)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 1548, in _validate
    raise except_orm('ValidateError', '\n'.join(error_msgs))
except_orm: ('ValidateError', u'Error occurred while validating the field(s) arch: Invalid XML for View Architecture!')
2013-11-03 07:58:38,548 14957 ERROR itmeedia openerp.netsvc: ValidateError
Error occurred while validating the field(s) arch: Invalid XML for View Architecture!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/netsvc.py", line 292, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 188, in execute_kw
    return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 144, in wrapper
    raise except_osv(inst.name, inst.value)
except_osv: ('ValidateError', u'Error occurred while validating the field(s) arch: Invalid XML for View Architecture!')
```

As you can see the problem is in view/account_payment.xml
The file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <!-- restore wizard functionality when making payments
          -->

        <record id="view_banking_payment_order_form_1" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">account.payment.order.form.banking-1</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="account_payment.view_payment_order_form" />
            <field name="model">payment.order</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <data>
                    <xpath expr="//button[@string='Make Payments']"
                           position="attributes">
                        <attribute name="name">launch_wizard</attribute>
                    </xpath>
                </data>
            </field>
        </record>

    </data>
</openerp>
```

Can anyone help me with this? I am new to XML as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is causing due to another module named as account_pain. If you look at this module, in file account_payment_view.xml you can see that this module is replacing the same button with string "Make Payment". SO if you have already installed the module account_pain, and if you try to install account_banking_payment_export, it will cause error because the button "Make Payment" is replaced in the module account_pain and is not currently in the view. So i would recommend to uninstall account_pain module or change the account_pain module to make the button invisible instead of replacing the button.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I had to install account_pain after I install SEPA module.